# 3 tables sql sum divided by a minus between two fields not working

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: formulario, viaverde and reparacoes.
one of the fields is equal in all tables, called matricula, i'm trying to group every arithmetic operation to it.
but i keep getting the error of matricula is ambiguous or synthax errors, how can i achieve this?

i tried the following code:

```
JOIN (
    SELECT matricula, (total)/(kmsTotais) AS custoKM
    FROM (
        SELECT matricula, SUM(kmfim - quilometragem) AS kmsTotais
        FROM formulario
        GROUP BY matricula
    ) e
    JOIN (
        SELECT matricula, abastecimento_euros as total FROM formulario
        UNION ALL
        SELECT matricula, custo as total FROM viaverde
        UNION ALL
        SELECT matricula, valor as total FROM reparacoes
    ) as subquery
    GROUP BY matricula
) i ON i.matricula = f.matricula
```

Comment: If a column name is in multiple tables in the join, you need to use `tablename.columnname`

Comment: You have no `ON` condition in the nested `JOIN`. It should be `ON e.matricula = subquery.matricula`

Comment: It looks like your query may be simplified a lot, can you share sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify `matricula` with the table aliases to make it unambiguous.

```
JOIN (
    SELECT e.matricula, SUM(total)/MAX(kmsTotais) AS custoKM
    FROM (
        SELECT matricula, SUM(kmfim - quilometragem) AS kmsTotais
        FROM formulario
        GROUP BY matricula
    ) e
    JOIN (
        SELECT matricula, abastecimento_euros as total FROM formulario
        UNION ALL
        SELECT matricula, custo as total FROM viaverde
        UNION ALL
        SELECT matricula, valor as total FROM reparacoes
    ) as subquery ON e.matricula = subquery.matricula
    GROUP BY e.matricula
) i ON i.matricula = f.matricula
```

You could also replace `ON e.matricula = subquery.matricula` with `USING (matricula)`. Since this indicates that the column name is the same in both tables, you don't need to qualify that column.

Comment: says subquery.total isn't on groupby

Comment: You need to aggregate all the totals for the same `matricula`.

Comment: yes i'll have plenty matricula and need to make this arithmetic operation and group them by each matricula

Comment: I already updates the answer to use `SUM(total)`

Comment: says: e.kmsTotais' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: i tried your last edit: ```syntax error to use near 'FROM ( SELECT matricula, SUM(kmfim - quilometragem) ```